# working with Keras on a Jupyter lab using Tensorflow

Tags: keras, kernel

I'm trying to use keras on a jupyter lab using tensorflow (python 3.6) through miniconda.

Jupyter lab keeps give me a restarting error(Kernel Restarting The kernel for Desktop/Transfer/Untitled.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.)

Because the kernel restarting error is evident whenever I try to import keras. The code I used is (from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array, array_to_img).
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRwFf.png)

Therefore, I assume that there is a problem between keras and kernel even though I already installed ipykernel in my tensorflow directory ((tensorflow) C:\Users\user). 
[Pip_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cwlh.png)

Still couldn't figure out this kernel and keras problem :(.